# Drawing rectangle on picturebox - how to limit area of rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm drawing rectangle on picturebox with mouse events:

```
private void StreamingWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
              rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
              this.Invalidate();       
    }

    private void StreamingWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

       if (painting == true)
        {

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            }
        }
    }

    private void StreamingWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {       
           if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
           {
               // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves
               rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
           }
           this.Invalidate();     
    }
```

After drawing rectangle i can capture inside of it, and save as jpg.

**What's my problem?**

I can draw retangle which borders are outside area of picturebox:

[image]

**How can i limit area of rectangle that border of picturebox is max allowed location of rectangle?**

Sorry for my english, i hope you'll understand my problem :)
So as a result i'd like to have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void StreamingWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{       
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves
    rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, Math.Min(e.X - rect.Left, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - rect.Left), Math.Min(e.Y - rect.Top, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - rect.Top));
  }
  this.Invalidate();     
}
```

Comment: I thought it will be much more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to achieve this, and I personally think more natural one from `UX` perspective, is: after `MouseUp` check if `BottomLeft` corner of rectangle is outside of area of picture box, if so, just bring it "back" and align it to the picture box's angle **just as you drawed**.

**EDIT**

Just to give you an idea what I'm talking about, a *pseudocode*

```
    private void StreamingWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
              if(rect.Right > myPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Right)
              {
                 rect.Width = myPictureBox.Right - rect.Left - someoffset;                     
              }       
              if(rect.Bottom > myPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Bottom)
              {
                 rect.Height= myPictureBox.Bottom - rect.Top - someoffset;                     
              }       
    }
```

Something like this. But you need to check this.

Comment: Maybe little hint how to do this? It will be connected with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.bottomleft.aspx , am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the rect coords to something

```
 rect = new Rectangle(min(e.X, pictureBoxX), min(e.Y, pictureBoxY), 0, 0);
```

You need to calculate pictureX and pictureY according to the location and position of the picture box.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for solving this is preventing rectangle to be drown outside of pictureBox control

```
private void StreamingWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (e.X < StreamingWindow.Width && Math.Abs(e.Y) < StreamingWindow.Height)
                // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y -rect.Top);
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Somebody can find this solution more useful